# SSIS REPLACE Function - Derived Column

Tags: ssis

I have a variable with a value of `'1617'`. It is a `DT_WSTR` datatype currently. Sometimes I need a string, others an integer.

I am using a derived column to replace the `'` values so that I can cast this value as an integer.

My replace function is not working.

```
REPLACE([User::schoolYear],"'","")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your supplied expression, is that you are not referencing the variable `schoolYear`.  Sometimes, you can address a variable as `@schoolYear` but the consistent, explicit syntax I would encourage is `@[User::schoolYear]` That way, you can identify the namespace in case someone like me has used a custom namespace.

Your Derived Column expression then becomes

```
REPLACE(@[User::schoolYear],"'","")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having space before and after the single quote, which is causing the replace to fail.

Modify the expression as given below. I have tested it. It is working fine.

```
REPLACE([User::schoolYear],"'","")
```